# How to display XSL style sheet in an HTML5 table

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I have an XML code that should display a XSL style sheet in an HTML5 table but I'm not sure if I'm heading the right direction

Would the XSD code have a major factor in whether or not the style sheet will display the XML contents in an HTML5 table or is there no correlation

```js
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type = "text/xsl" href = "nutrition.xsl"?>
<nutrition:items xmlns:nutrition = "http://www.grandmascookies.com/nutrition">
<product name = "Grandma White's Cookies">
<item>
        <servingsize> 
                <amount> 1 </amount> 
                <unit> package </unit> 
                </servingsize>  
        <calories> 
                <amount> 260 </amount> 
                <unit> calories </unit> 
                </calories>
        <caloriesFat> 
                <amount> 100 </amount> 
                <unit> grams </unit> 
                </caloriesFat>    
        <gramsFat> 
                <amount> 11 </amount> 
                <unit> grams </unit> 
                </gramsFat>  
</item>
</product>
</nutrition:item>
```

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0"
    xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method = "html" doctype-system = "about:legacy-compat"/>
<xsl:template match = "/">
    <html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta charset = "utf-8">        
            <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css"/>
            <title> Cookies </title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table border = "1" syle = "background-color: blue">
                <thead>
                    <tr> 
                        <th> Calories</th>
                        <th> Fat - Calories</th>
                        <th> Fat - Grams </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

XSDs are irrelevant unless you want to validate the xml input - completely removed from XSL.

I think you have a misunderstanding about XSL. XSL isn't being displayed by an HTML5 table, it is generating HTML (or anything else you want).

Your stylesheet is matching the root node ("/", in your case nutrition:items) and generating the code every time it finds it (ie once). Now you want to match, in the right place, every item for a row in the table:

```
                </thead>
              <xsl:for-each select="./product/item">
                  <!-- Generate html table row  -->
                  <tr>
                  <!-- Calories (relative to current node)  -->
                      <td><xsl:value-of select="calories/amount"/></td>
                  <!-- Repeat for other fields. Probably want the name somewhere, too  -->
                  </tr>
              </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
```

You could also use <xsl:apply-templates...> and <xsl:template-match select="calories/amount">